# In typescript, how does the 'this' type really infer its type?

Tags: typescript, types, this

In typescript, I would like to use the `this` keywork to type some properties of my class. However, I face a problem I can't solve.
What I would like to do is something like :

```js
export class Animal{
/*some properties*/
}

export class Population{
    AnimalConstructor : typeof Animal = Animal;
    animal : InstanceType<this['AnimalConstructor']>;

    createAnimal(){
        this.animal = new this.AnimalConstructor();//Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<this["AnimalConstructor"]>'
    }
}
```

Doing that, I have the error : `Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<this["AnimalConstructor"]>'` on line 10.
However, this code works well:

```js
export class Animal{
/*some properties*/
}

export class Population{
    AnimalConstructor : typeof Animal = Animal;
    animal : Animal;

    createAnimal(){
        this.animal = new this.AnimalConstructor();
    }

}
```

I can't understand why the last one work and the first one doesn't. This is probably due to the way the compiler infers the type of the `this` keyword. But I didn't find any docs able to explain that behaviour neither. The official document only says : 'a special type called this refers dynamically to the type of the current class.' - which doesn't explain why the example above doesn't work.

Comment: The polymorphic `this` type narrows in subclasses, so if what you're doing won't work for all possible subclasses, you shouldn't use `this`.  Consider [this demonstration](https://tsplay.dev/ND8e4N) of what happens if you subclass `Population` with `DogPopulation`; the `animal` property is of type `Dog`, so `createAnimal()` is improperly implemented.  If you change `this` to `Population` then the `animal` property of `DogPopulation` is just `Animal` as I suppose you want.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: thanks for your answer ! Indeed, you are right ; my question was ambiguous and over simplificated.
What I do is not : `this.animal = new Animal();` but `this.animal = new this.AnimalConstructor();` and so if I don't mistake, in the example of your link, all should correctly work ? I updated the question with the desired line

Comment: The `this` type is an implicit generic type parameter, and `InstanceType` is implemented as a conditional type, so `InstanceType<this["xxx"]>` is a generic conditional type... and the compiler really can't reason about generic conditional types (it's essentially the same issue as described in [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)) and so it complains.  In your new code, the only reasonable approach (with your existing typings) is to use a type assertion [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/NrQ8aw).  Does *that* fully address the question? If so, ✍; if not, ❓

Comment: It can be the answer ; however, I think the problem in your link is more complex for the compiler than this one ? For example, I just noticed that this syntax is accepted by the compiler : 
`this.animal = new (this.AnimalConstructor.bind(this.AnimalConstructor))();` and then the type of `this.animal` is correctly infered to `Animal`
Do you have documentation on how the compiler works in this kind of cases ?

Comment: I don't understand your question and I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing.  I'm kind of concerned that you're expanding the scope of the question for each comment I post, which isn't promising.  What can we do here to limit the scope of the question to something concrete so I can either post an answer or leave to do something else?

Comment: Yes, you are right that my last suggestion was a bit out of the scope ! And, indeed, it doesn't work on typescript lang context while work on my local machine.
I think the answer that the compiler can't reason about generic conditional types can be the good one ; but I would love to understand why - or to have documentation about how the compiler work in this kind of case

Comment: I will explain what I can, but [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) is as close to official documentation as you're going to get.  The TS team considers the github issue list to be documentation, and that issue was filed by the TS team lead, so it's canonical.  The issue goes through the various options and how it could be addressed.  If you want documentation that `this` is implicitly generic, see [ms/TS#4910](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910), and I can link to the definition of `InstanceType` to show it's generic.  Would that suffice in an answer?

Comment: Note that every caveat you add, like, "this is good, but XXXX", just delays my ability to decide whether I should or should not be writing an answer.  So I'm hoping that you'll say something like "yes that would be good" or "no, this isn't what I want", so I could either write an answer, or run away screaming.

Comment: Yes, of course, if the link are the best documentations we can get, that would be enough ! Thanks you for the informations and for your time !

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) acts as an implicit [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the current class type, but is only specified as a type argument when you access a specific instance of the class or its subclass.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#4910](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910) for the implementing pull request that describes `this` as an implicit type parameter.)  That means when you use the `this` type you get the benefits—and the drawbacks—of generics.

The [`InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), as you can see from its [definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/68d8be4f1d89d94a543d93fcedad17f3e4ef297b/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1610):

> ```
> type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = 
>   T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
> ```

So, inside the body of the `Population` class definition, the type `InstanceType<this['AnimalConstructor']>` is a *generic conditional type* (a conditional type that depends on at least one as-yet-unspecified type parameter).  And, unfortunately, the compiler cannot really reason about such types.

---

When evaluating the value `new this.AnimalConstructor()`, the compiler *widens* the apparent type of `this` to `Animal`, because you're accessing a specific property on a generic-typed value, and the compiler does this widening as an approximation to make things easier.  (See [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194) for a source.)  And so `this.AnimalConstructor` is seen as type `typeof Animal` and thus `new this.AnimalConstructor()` is seen as type `Animal`:

```
const ac = this.AnimalConstructor;
//const ac: typeof Animal
const a = new ac();
//const a: Animal;
```

But the compiler *defers* evaluation of generic conditional types like `InstanceType<this["AnimalConstructor"]>`, and therefore ends up treating such types as essentially *opaque*.  If you try to assign a value to a variable of such a type, the compiler will almost certainly complain because it can't verify that the value is compatible with the type.  As a human being you can examine the value is and understand the meaning behind the conditional type and say "yes this is fine", but the compiler mostly sees the type as a black box and it has no idea what might be compatible with it.  (The closest thing to documentation for this issue is [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)).

So you get an error:

```
this.animal = a; // error!
// Type 'Animal' is not assignable to 
// type 'InstanceType<this["AnimalConstructor"]>'
```

---

If you want to keep your types as they are, then probably the best way forward is just to accept that you're smarter than the compiler.  Since you're sure that `new this.AnimalConstructor()` is clearly of type `InstanceType<this["AnimalConstructor"]>` no matter what `this` turns out to be in subclasses, then you can just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that fact to the compiler to stop it from worrying about things it can't figure out:

```
createAnimal() {
  const ac = this.AnimalConstructor;    
  const a = new ac();
  this.animal = a as InstanceType<this['AnimalConstructor']>; // okay
}
```

or just

```
createAnimal() {
  this.animal = new this.AnimalConstructor() as typeof this.animal; // okay
}
```

That works and you can move on.  It's not as type safe as it could be if the compiler were smarter, but it's the probably best you can do without refactoring... for example, to make `Population` *explicitly* generic in the instance type of `AnimalConstructor` so you can control when generics get widened and avoid conditional types altogether:

```
export class Population<T extends Animal> {
  constructor(public AnimalConstructor: new () => T) {
    this.animal = new AnimalConstructor(); // things should be initialized
  }
  animal: T

  createAnimal() {
    this.animal = new this.AnimalConstructor(); // okay
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4EEB2BLAWxSTgG8AoOOAegCo0IDg4woIxhY9g1bryAvuXKhIsRKgxwACuwCuqGHgg4ylbPiJIAwirQwochDGgAuODACeHCADMNhYnAC8DrQG51KTcQCE5gEkcfW8EYAAVa2AAHhgACzw0AG0AclxHHT0DIxMoFIBdAD53Gmo4HAh4PHwlYjwAL2qAczhbaDgGJjgoYHQVOAC4ABMVFPg5HCHOEMmAGgsEzAQUOTQeOE42KExAXg3AIj3hKgQelBhgdK0ACgBKNSojrLgUBBcFxIA6C+JdYOzjaE891KCEez3MVhs9i+SHUD1+T1eOGAAHcnggboD7tRqCD4ShzNDMVR4h9vBlXigStiNlAtr5YaU4JEOHA0j4kCk4IlypUnhg8E0cCgAEZIZgmOAM6kQ5gpIIzMLMmIk5IAImhP30hn+UFVRU5O0A+HsMlXvMlaCl8ga-UIRKKxRapDVZbW5ArFRkQADWKEs6iE6mOvTO0IATDc7vdTeanK4kajTc7fq7oBH0BYonY3mgzeyqWVvb7-YJhCJwNB4Mh0JhZGAFKdlDhQ9FwhsQGdJphoYVI7itTlU3XRXgXkn+zrzPG4BHnD3wrcKEDo+zESi3N8XQOoDdi1QY0hzOFDogTiH2RHF1HFrnyXG14n2Zq-rkMZ6fX6qEIA0A)

Comment: thanks, that's really clear and the links are useful to understand !