# Using "this" type inside a conditional type doesn't seem to work in Typescript - why?

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with inheritance, and I'd like to create an abstract variable in a parent class that's typed based off both the parent's and child classes' properties using `this`. The idea usually works fine, but I seem to be running into a wall when using `this` inside a conditional type. Is that combination possible in Typescript?

For example, let's say I have class `Car` and `Car` has the sub type I want `NumberSubsets`:

```
type NumberSubsets<Subset extends Car> =
    Record<{
        [key in Exclude<keyof Subset, 'all_numbers'>]: Subset[key] extends number ? key : never;
    }[Exclude<keyof Subset, 'all_numbers'>], number>;

abstract class Car {
    public abstract all_numbers: NumberSubsets<this>;

    public doors: number;
    public is_truck: boolean;
    public wheels: number;
}
```

where `all_numbers` is a generated subset of `Car` with all the number types in `Car` (`doors` and `wheels`).

Now when I go to create my subclass:

```
class Sedan extends Car {
    public all_numbers: NumberSubsets<this>;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.all_numbers = {
            doors: 5, // does not work
            wheels: 6
        };
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
Type '{ doors: number; wheels: number; }' is not assignable to type 'NumberSubsets<this>'.   
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'doors' does not exist in type 'NumberSubsets<this>'
```

Why is that? After some testing, it seems like it's not possible to use the type `this` with conditional types. Is that true? Or is there a way to make this work?

`NumberSubsets<Sedan>` works fine and I *could* replace `this` with `Car` or `Sedan`, but I'd like to make things work with `this` as it's easier to use.

*Edit: Replaced term "ternary" with "condtional type." Thanks @jcalz

Comment: What you're calling "ternary/extend" is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html); please [edit] to use that term so that your question is more easily searchable.

Comment: The `this` type is an implicit generic type parameter and so inside the body of your class, ` NumberSubsets<this>` is a conditional type that depends on a generic type parameter.  The compiler can't really do much accurate reasoning about such types; it either leaves them as unevaluated and you can get errors because it's opaque, or it tried to eagerly evaluate them and you can get errors because it's approximate. Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh I see. I use generics quite a bit, and I suppose I'm used to the latter case - Typescript eagerly evaluating. Maybe this is one of those cases where TS can't do that. *I wonder if anyone can get around this, but that seems correct

Comment: "get around" by something other than a type assertion?  I mean, you can always use type assertions when you're smarter than the compiler.  Maybe I'm missing something about what you're expecting to see

Comment: Ah, I think I just *needed to read more about it. Your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75949199/in-typescript-how-does-the-this-type-really-infer-its-type) helped a lot, and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) is what I was looking for. Thanks jcalz!